# Mysql2::Error: BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY or JSON column 'body' can't have a default value

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I have migration:

```
lass ChangeDefaultValueBodyForBlogPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :blog_posts, :body, :text, :null => false
    change_column :comments, :text, :text, :null => false
  end

  def down
    change_column :comments, :text, :text, :default => nil
    change_column :blog_posts, :body, :text, :default => nil
  end
end
```

rake db:migrate display error:

**Mysql2::Error: BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY or JSON column 'body' can't have a default value: ALTER TABLE `blog_posts` CHANGE `body` `body` text DEFAULT '' NOT NULL/home/user/projects/projectname/db/migrate/20120508203410_change_default_value_body_for_blog_posts.rb:3:in `up'**

I use ubuntu 16.04,

mysql server 5.7(Version: 5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1
Version: 5.7.12-0ubuntu1
Version: 5.7.11-0ubuntu6
)

I looked in google, solving this issue need change

sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

to

```
sql-mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

But my.conf file is empty.

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

How solve this issue, please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the correct my.cnf:

```
sudo find / -name "*.cnf"

/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
```

I edited /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf based on

```
strace mysql ";" 2>&1  | grep cnf

stat("/etc/my.cnf", 0x7ffda9472660)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/etc/mysql/my.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=683, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/my.cnf", O_RDONLY)     = 3
stat("/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=8, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 4
stat("/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=55, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 4
stat("/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3034, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 4
stat("/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=21, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 4
stat("/root/.my.cnf", 0x7ffda9472660)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/root/.mylogin.cnf", 0x7ffda9472660) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Once you find the correct file add **sql-mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"** below [mysqld] statement

Comment: Doesn't work in MySQL 8 - causes crash on restart.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from MySQL 8.0.13, it is now possible to have a default value for TEXT/BLOB field. However, literal default needs to be specified as an expression.

For example, this is valid:

```sql
`title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ('Title')
```

But this will produce an error:

```sql
`title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Title'
```

Comment: Thanks, it really did the trick - after correcting it in dump file import to MySQL 8 worked.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution:
Need add in my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Comment: In my case, I solved it by setting sql-mode="" in the MySQL config file (/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf in my case) and restarting MySQL server afterwards (using sudo systemctl restart mysql). So changing a setting in the MySQL config may help here.

Comment: Doesn't work in MySQL 8 - causes crash on restart.

Answer (score 0):

I had no problems with migrating on my local machine using mysql from xampp. Only on the production server it started failing. I figured out that xampp runs mariadb instead of plain mysql. So using mariaDB on the server fixed my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Check your sql code again error clearly said above 'body' not a default value 

**Example :**

```
 `completed` text NOT NULL  DEFAULT 'false',
```

After remove **Default value**

```
`completed` text NOT NULL,
```

Now hopefully your error is gone.
and sorry for my english.

Comment: NOTE: this will probably break your code, if you relied on your queries, that if you ommit the field `completed` it will get the default value. You have to adapt your code accordingly too

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem this way: I once wanted to export my mySql database on a server and import it in another server (CPanel host). phpMyAdmin kept giving this error on one of the fields of one of database tables each time I tried. I then went to my source host; opened phpMyAdmin and opened that table structure and removed default value for that field. Then I exported again and this time it worked.